# Flex TabbedViewNavigator deactivate event in a view

Tags: apache-flex, air, components

I have a TabbedView application it looks like this:

```
<s:TabbedViewNavigator width="100%" height="100%" left="0" bottom="0" right="0">
    <s:ViewNavigator label="viewA" firstView="views.viewA" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="viewB" firstView="views.viewB" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</s:TabbedViewNavigator>
```

This will create a buttonbar with two buttons at the bottom of the application.
Now I can easily switch between viewA and viewB.

When I define a button in viewA to trigger a CallOut (component in flex) is will appear nice and smooth.
I also created a close button to close the CallOut.

```
callout.close();
```

So far so good.

The problem will exist when I use the button to open the CallOut pane in viewA.
Then switch to viewB, the CallOut pane still exists on the screen and did not close.

So I tried these events:
viewDeactivate or/and deactivate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        viewDeactivate="viewDeactivates()"

        deactivate="viewDeactivates()"> <!-- or this -->
```

But it seems that there is no event when switching between tabs viewA and viewB.
viewDeactivate or deactivate didn't do anything.

I could use a eventlistener on the TabbedViewNavigator and then close the CallOut component if exists in viewA or viewB in the TabbedViewNavigatorView, but this is not a nice way to program, especially when you have multiple CallOut components.

Does anyone know, if there is a good solution for this problem? 
Would helped me a lot, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an event argument into the function for it to work!

```
viewDeactivate="viewDeactivates(event)"
```

then

```
private function viewDeactivates(event:Event):void
            {
                callout.close();
            }
```